# Source for non TR 20A outlets?

Tags: electrical, receptacle

Are there suppliers that will sell 20A non TR outlets?  From all the grief I've read about the TR outlets, when I wire my garage, I would rather mount all the outlets 5.5 feet off the ground, and use non-TR outlets.

Answer (score 3):

Sorry but shopping questions are off topic but Leviton sells 15 and 20 amp non tamper receptacles, in both spec grade and builder (crap) grade. Every big box store sells both tamper and old style in both 15 and 20 amp.

Comment: Should I delete the question?

Comment: Deleting would be the proper thing unless it is reworded, but you have an answer that should help if accepted it closes it and others may find it useful.

Answer (score 0):

Apologies for the bad question.

Ed Beal is correct.  Looking online does find sources with non TR outlets.  Amazon.ca carries them.

Usually however they are scattered about, and it's not clear from the caption whether they are TR or not.  This requires a lot of click, and reading the details to find.

Comment: Find the manufacturers' catalogue, get a part number, search for the part number.